# Difference of one element with all other elements after Groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data set as shown below:

```html
Date       Lon_s lat_s HLON_cv HLAT_cv
1853-11-09 31 -10.4 293.85 5.2
1853-11-09 302.3 3.6 290.15 4.9
1853-12-01 85.5 -7.5 84.62 -6.88
1853-12-01 85.5 -7.5 78.2 -6.83
1853-12-01 88 -8.6 84.62 -6.88
1853-12-01 88 -8.6 78.2 -6.83
1853-12-01 86.6 -7.8 84.62 -6.88
1853-12-01 86.6 -7.8 78.2 -6.83
```

For each Date I want to take one element from lon_s and have a difference with all other values of HLON.
For example: For the 1853-11-09 : 
lon 31- HLON 293.85 
lon 31- HLON 290.15 
lon 302.3-HLON 293.85 
lon 302.3-HLON 290.15 
with corresponding lat-HLAT as well.

I have used`for group, values in df.groupby(df['Date']):` to groupby date but need help for rest of the part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code and let me know if it works:

```
diff_df = pd.DataFrame()
for group, values in df.groupby(df['Date']):
      lat_diff = []; lon_diff = []
      for i in range(len(values['Lon_s'])):
         for j in range(len(values['HLON_cv']):
                lon_diff.append(values['Lon_s'].iloc[i] - values['HLON_cv'].iloc[j])

      for m in range(len(values['Lat_s'])):
         for n in range(len(values['HLAT_cv']):
                lat_diff.append(values['Lat_s'].iloc[m] - values['HLAT_cv'].iloc[n])
      df = pd.DataFrame({"date": group, "Lat_Diff": lat_diff, "Long_Diff":lon_diff})
      diff_df = diff_df.append(df)
```

This should create a dataframe for you in the format:

```
       Date   Lon_diff  Lat_diff
0  1853-11-09    -262.85    -15.60
1  1853-11-09    -259.15    -15.30
2  1853-12-01       0.88     -0.62
3  1853-12-01       7.30     -0.67
4  1853-12-01       0.88     -0.62
5  1853-12-01       7.30     -0.67
6  1853-12-01       0.88     -0.62
7  1853-12-01       7.30     -0.67
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the following function (with another function inside):

```
def myFun(grp):
    def myDiff(col1, col2):
        return col1.iloc[0] - col2
    return pd.DataFrame({'Lon_diff': myDiff(grp.Lon_s, grp.HLON_cv),
                         'Lat_diff': myDiff(grp.Lat_s, grp.HLAT_cv)})
```

It generates a DataFrame composed of 2 columns: *Lon_diff* and *Lat_diff*,
each with respective difference.

Then join the result of application of this function to the original DataFrame:

```
result = df.join(df.groupby('Date').apply(myFun))
```

The result is:

```
         Date  Lon_s  Lat_s  HLON_cv  HLAT_cv  Lon_diff  Lat_diff
0  1853-11-09   31.0  -10.4   293.85     5.20   -262.85    -15.60
1  1853-11-09  302.3    3.6   290.15     4.90   -259.15    -15.30
2  1853-12-01   85.5   -7.5    84.62    -6.88      0.88     -0.62
3  1853-12-01   85.5   -7.5    78.20    -6.83      7.30     -0.67
4  1853-12-01   88.0   -8.6    84.62    -6.88      0.88     -0.62
5  1853-12-01   88.0   -8.6    78.20    -6.83      7.30     -0.67
6  1853-12-01   86.6   -7.8    84.62    -6.88      0.88     -0.62
7  1853-12-01   86.6   -7.8    78.20    -6.83      7.30     -0.67
```